# Calling transaction.commit() inside commit_on_success block in Django

Tags: python, mysql, django, celery

I have code like:

```
@transaction.commit_on_success()
def foo():
    # Performs various database operations and may raise exception
    do_stuff()

    my_object = MyModel.objects.create()

    # Commit transaction so Celery task will see the newly created object
    transaction.commit()

    # Async call Celery task that does something with the new object
    my_celery_task.delay(my_object.id)
```

Does this do what I expect it to do, i.e.:

- If no exceptions occur, `transaction.commit()` performs commit
- If `do_stuff()` raises exception, transaction is rolled back

I'm on Django 1.4 and MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`transaction.commit_on_success()` will commit if the view returns normally, and abort if an exception is raised. In your case, it should "work" but is possibly not the best solution - since you have to manually commit anyway, you'd probably be better using `transaction.commit_manually()` (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.commit_manually):

```
@transaction.commit_manually()
def foo():
    try:
        # Performs various database operations and may raise exception
        do_stuff()
        my_object = MyModel.objects.create()

    except Exception, e:
        # oops, let's forget about it
        transaction.rollback()
        raise

    else:
        # Commit transaction so Celery task will see the newly created object
        transaction.commit()
        # Async call Celery task that does something with the new object
        my_celery_task.delay(my_object.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. According to Django docs:

> If the function returns successfully, then Django will commit all work
>   done within the function at that point. If the function raises an
>   exception, though, Django will roll back the transaction.

From [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.commit_on_success)